# Lista de todos os aplicativos instalados

Tags: android

Estou querendo aprender a criar uma lista com todos os aplicativos instalados do Android. Como faço para mostar em uma `ListView` todos os aplicativos instalados no smartphone?

Answer (score 1):

Segue:

```
   PackageManager packageManager=getPackageManager();
        List<ApplicationInfo> list = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>(0);
        for(ApplicationInfo ap:list){
            values.add(ap.packageName);
        }
        ListView lista =  ListView.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.lista));
        lista.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values));
```

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo o código para pegar a lista de activities/aplicações instaladas no Android:

```
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final List pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
```

Espero que tenha ajudado, qualquer dúvida só chamar.

Comment: Sou ignorante em como usar este seu código. Preciso de um programa pra rodar isso? Ou no celular tem um local  certo para rodar?

Comment: Se você tem dúvidas sobre onde colocar esse código, sua dúvida é muito maior do que você demostrou na pergunta. Comece do começo e vá aumentando seu conhecimento aos poucos. Não dá pra começar já do alto.